# Unable to get div to fade-in then smooth switch to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to get an intro to my website by fading-in my name and info, and after around 5 seconds, I want that div to go away, smoothly transitioning to a full website. Currently, when I try to fade out that intro, the code is not letting me add text on top of that hidden div. Im thinking that this may require the use of Javascript, but I do not know how.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>My Name</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="My Organization">
    <meta name="author" content="My Name">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Youth | Society</title>
    
    <! -- FONTS -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    
    <! -- Mobile META tags -- >
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    
    
    <! -- CSS FILE -- >
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="website.css">

</head>

<body>

    <intro>
        <div class="text_paragraph">
    <h1>My Name</h1>
    <h3>My School</h3>
    <h3>Grade 10</h3>
        
        </div>
    </intro>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url(footer_lodyas.png);
}



intro {
    color: grey;
    font-family: sans-serif;;
    font-size: 19px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 200px;
 
}





 .text_paragraph {               
    -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 2s;
    opacity:0;
}

.bdy {
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut{
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    35% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    72% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    75% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your code you are fading in, have you look for how to do fade out in CSS?

Comment: yes. I took out the fading out code because it would only make the div invisible, not make it delete

Comment: try with `display: none;` in fade out animation instead `opacity: 0;`

Comment: I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Can you edit my code including the fade out?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var $el = $('.text_paragraph');
$el.fadeIn(5000, function(){$el.fadeOut(3000)})
```

Comment: That does not work. When that code is entered, the intro fades out but reappears

Comment: hmm with jQuery would be a lot easier, I am going to put that option

Comment: ok. I have edited my main css code. that code seems to keep the intro element invisible, however, I cannot place other elements on the space that the intro is taking up. Essentially, I want the intro element to "delete" itself after the fade out so that I can place other elements on the space that the intro element was.

Comment: for that part is `display: none` for, if you use opacity, element keeps its space.